# Prioritize some job instanciation inside a parallel stage

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

My pipeline inherit (with `include`) from a corporate pipeline. There are sequential stages in my pipeline and the final one contains three jobs:

[image: There are 2 of 3 running parallel jobs inside the same stage]

Since the gitlab-runner is very resources limited, all the jobs can't be run in the same time. Gitlab seems to launch the job in alphebetical order inside a same stage.

The job "sonarqube" is the most expected job to be run first, how to prioritize its instantiation over the others while still keeping them in parallel?

In my `.gitlab-ci.yml` the jobs are already overriden in the expected order but this does not work:

```
include:
  - project: "project/parent"
    ref: production
    file: "main.yml"

# ...

sonarqube:
  stage: analysis

license-finder:
  allow_failure: true

checkmarx:
  dependencies: []
  timeout: 1 hours
```

Do you have any leads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to prioritize some jobs by delaying the others with the following keywords `when: delayed` and `start_in: x seconds`.

Here is a working example:

```
sonarqube:
  stage: analysis

license-finder:
  stage: analysis
  when: delayed
  start_in: 1 seconds

checkmarx:
  stage: analysis
  when: delayed
  start_in: 1 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

You can limit parallelism with [resource_group attribute](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/01/21/introducing-resource-groups/) in your `.gitlab-ci.yml` but don't think that can give exactly what you need...
Maybe you can configure these jobs as manual and trigger them with an [API call](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/jobs.html#play-a-job) in a previous job? something like:

```
include:
  - project: "project/parent"
    ref: production
    file: "main.yml"

call_jobs:
  script:
    # execute first job
    - curl --request POST --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: <your_access_token>" "https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/1/jobs/1/play"
    - sleep 60
    # execute the second job after some time 
    .....

sonarqube:
  stage: analysis
  when: manual

license-finder:
  allow_failure: true
  when: manual

checkmarx:
  dependencies: []
  timeout: 1 hours
  when: manual
```

You can even get the status of your most expensive job and trigger the other two once that's completed...
With `GET /projects/:id/pipelines/:pipeline_id/jobs` you can get the ID of your most expensive job (can't use JOB_ID env variable because your not inside the job which you want get the ID of!) and then with `GET /projects/:id/jobs/:job_id` you can get the status...